# how to remove or filter null element from nested list of list

Tags: java

I have category list in my model, and there is a categorylist of this list as a parameter like this,

```
CategoryModel{
    List<CategoryModel> categories;
}
```

I have category structure like binary search tree, it means there are multiple times nested multiple categorylist.

I wrote code to find categories which does not have any product and sub category using recursive but I can not remove or filter elements because of `not supported operation` error.

How can I solve this?

```
private void checkNullCategory(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(categoryModelList)) {
        for (CategoryModel categoryModel : categoryModelList) {
            if (!categoryModel.getProducts().isEmpty()) {
                if (!categoryModel.getCategories().isEmpty()) {
                    checkNullCategory(categoryModel.getCategories());
                }
            } else {
                if(categoryModel.getCategories().isEmpty()){
                    categoryCode.add(categoryModel.getCode());
 
                    checkNullCategory(categoryModel.getCategories());
                    //categoryModelList.remove(categoryModel); it is giving unsupported operation error
                }else{
                    checkNullCategory(categoryModel.getCategories());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get an UnsupportedOperationException when trying to remove an element from a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965747/why-do-i-get-an-unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-to-remove-an-element-f)

Comment: Also, after fixing the UnsupportedOperationException, you'll get a ConcurrentModificationException because you're trying to change the list you're iterating over, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the ways to obtain a mutable List in this case.
You can create an ArrayList or any kind of list directly and then perform add/remove operations.

Something like,

```
String[] flowers = { "Ageratum", "Allium", "Poppy", "Catmint" };
List<String> flowerList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(flowers));
```