# how to change string array to array. String[] to ArrayList<string> format conversion

Tags: java, android

How do I convert `String Array` to `Array List`:

`String[]` to `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607289/converting-array-to-list-in-java Check dis..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.clear();

for(int i=0;i<StringArray.length;i++)
{
    list.add(StringArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
String [] strings = new String [] {"stack", "overflow" };
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strings));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
String[] arr = { "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100", };

ArrayList<String> arr_list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr_list.add(arr[i]);
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> arr_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] words = {"ace", "boom", "crew", "dog", "eon"};  

List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);  

for (String e : wordList)  
{  
    System.out.println(e);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

- Use the `Arrays.asList()` method

  ```
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strings);
  ```
- Create a new `ArrayList` and copy the elements of the array (not recommended)

  ```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (String str : strings)
  {
      list.add(str);
  }
  ```

Hope this helps.