# Checking if Integer is in Array Java does not return expected values

Tags: java, arrays

I have looked in many places online and all seem to give me the same solution. So it's obvious that I have made some sort of silly mistake I cannot see. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks a mill.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] outcomes = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};        
        int count = 0;      
        for(int y = 1; y<=6; y++){      
            if(Arrays.asList(outcomes).contains(y)){                
                count++;                
                System.out.println("outcomes contains "+ y);                
            }               
        }           
        System.out.println(count);  
    }
```

The final output should be 6 but it is 0.

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2607289/4186297)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList(int[])
```

returns a single-element list. The one element is the `int[]` you have passed in.

If you change the declaration

```
int[] outcomes
```

to

```
Integer[] outcomes
```

you'll get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Two things should be corrected in your code:

1. Changing int[] to Integer[] (as sugested Marko Topolnik in previous answer)
2. Moving Arrays.asList befor for loop. Now array is converted to list 6 times.

After this changes code will look as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] outcomes = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    List outcomesList = Arrays.asList(outcomes);
    int count = 0;

    for(int y = 1; y<=6; y++){
        if(outcomesList.contains(y)){
            count++;
            System.out.println("outcomes contains "+ y);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```