# Jasper Library no compile with Parameter

Tags: parameters, report, subreport

I'm having the following problem: I have a report with sub report, where and passed as one parameter Collection. when I run into the iReports the resulado comes as planned, but when I run in my Java code, the following error appears:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; can not be cast to java.util.Collection
```

the library version 5.5.1 and and my code that generates the PDF is:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass () getClassLoader () getResourceAsStream ("/" + filename)..;

JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load (s);
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport (jd);

JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport (jr, parameters, jdbcTemplate.getDataSource () getConnection ().);

byte [] = pdfBytes JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf (jp);
return pdfBytes;
```

Comment: show your parameters object initialization

Comment: I was sending in my one obj parameters of type String [], where the first report performed correctly, but the sub report gave the error. By modifying the parameter to List <String> both worked properly. ps. I used the following tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607289/converting-array-to-list-in-java