# Pushing Dynamically into List/Array

Tags: java

The following line will working perfectly fine because I manually input the "new item(1,2,3)" into the item array?

But what i'm trying to do here is loop through a file and push 
**"new item(1,2,3)"** dynamically into "Lines[] item"

Which I currently got no idea how to go about pushing it in. THe following image is what happens when i do ** item.(Function)**
[image]
Any advice?

```
 Lines[] item
         = {new item(0, 2, 1),
            new item(0, 3, 4),
            new item(0, 4, 2),
           };

    Test test = new Test(item);
     // Test is a java file which will accept this
     public Test(List<Lines> item) {
        this.edges = edges;
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting array to list in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607289/converting-array-to-list-in-java)

Comment: @px5x2 YOu mean i should push "new item(0, 3, 4) " into a array?

Comment: its not really clear what you are trying to do here, you want to create an array dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your array into a list you will be able to "push" an item into it.
You can do this by changing "Lines[] item" into "List<Lines> item". Then you will be able to call the Add method on the list passing the item you want to "push" into item.

Comment: How do i actually add new Edge(0,0,0) ? I tried to do item.add(0,0,0) but welll cant.

Comment: do .add(new Edge(0,0,0))

Comment: use the toArray method with an empty array of the list's size .toArray(new Edge[list.size()])

Answer (score 1):

```
//Read data from some excel file using poi / jxl

String inputArray = td.getDataFromExcel().get(index);

//Read the array
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(inputArray.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    // perform the operation of your choice
}
```