# Android AIDL List of Integers

Tags: android

I have an AIDL file where I want to return a list of integers. Simply like:

```
interface blah {
    List<Integer> getSubscriptionsForUser(int user);
}
```

But I can't do this because AIDL doesn't support java.lang.Integer it only supports primitives. But I can't do a list of primitives because java doesn't support primitve types.

Do I really need to make a custom parcelable class to make a list of integers that I can pass over binder? Or is there something obvious I'm just missing.

Comment: no just use an array? `int[]`

Comment: omg... make that an answer and get some points

Comment: was being lazy as you have to actually explain in answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `int[]` with AIDL interfaces

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html#Create

---

To create your array you can use:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572820/413127

```
List<Integer> list = ...;
int[] array = new int[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { array[i] = list.get(i) };
```

To create your list back on the other side you can use this method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607335/413127

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```