# How can I separate a single String into two parts?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a text document that consists of a number of lines, each of which has a username, a comma, and a password. For example,

```
Joe, pass1
Sally, badpassword
Ahmed, goodpassword
```

And so forth.

I can read those lines into my program without any trouble. After that I want to separate them into an `ArrayList`. `String.split()` says it should separate them into an array. I need an `ArrayList`, and anyway the when I invoke `split()` my `String` is unchanged. So I don't know how to proceed.

This is where I think I am having a problem:

```
                while (true) {
                    if ((str = br1.readLine()) != null)
                        break;
                    out.println(str);
                    str.split(",");
                    userstr.add(str);
                }
```

This is the whole class:

```
public BuggerGUI() {
    super("password");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));
    userL = new JLabel("username");
    add(userL);
    userT = new JTextField(10);
    add(userT);
    passL = new JLabel("password: ");
    add(passL);
    passT = new JPasswordField(10);
    add(passT);
    blankL = new JLabel();
    add(blankL);
    loggin =  new JButton("login");
    add(loggin);
    handler Handler = new handler();
    userT.addActionListener(Handler);
    passT.addActionListener(Handler);
    loggin.addActionListener(Handler);
}

private class handler implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String user = userT.getText();
        String pass = passT.getText();
        if (event.getSource() == loggin) {
            out.println("username: " + user);
            out.println("password: " + pass);
            try {
                ArrayList userstr = new ArrayList();
                FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\passlist.txt");
                BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
                String str;
                while (true) {
                    if ((str = br1.readLine()) != null)
                        break;
                    out.println(str);
                    str.split(",");
                    userstr.add(str);
                }     
                for (int i = 0; i < userstr.size();)
                    if (userT.equals(userstr.get(i)))
                        out.print("cool");   
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i split the strings @SLaks

Comment: You state that you are "having problems" but don't tell us what those problems are.

Comment: ....and what's the problem?

Comment: Split the Strings how? By what criteria? To what effect?

Comment: it is not spliting the strings
the text doc is set up like this
Username,Password 
I am trying to split the string at the comma

Comment: If your goal is to cause frustration over miscommunication, it's unfortunately working. Please fix this; please tell the important details. Also please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections.

Comment: 5 seconds of research would give you the answer.  Why don't you look for examples of how to split a string in java?  like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: nothing I have all the user name's and password's stored in a text doc

Comment: @RickS i have looked at that but is dose not work for what I want to do. I want to have is stored in a arraylist.

Comment: Yes it does work, you just aren't using it correctly.

Comment: String is immutable type.

Comment: @RickS gave you the answer to how to split the strings. Here is how to store that array in a List: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607289/converting-array-to-list-in-java. I think that answers your question, doesn't it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You used to have

```
str.split(",");
```

and `split()` is a `void` method. It doesn't alter `str`.

you could fix it by replacing `str.split(",")` with: `str = str.split(",")`, or you could put it all on one line like:

```
while ((str = br1.readLine()) != null)
    userstr.add(str.split(",")[0]);
```

Comment: You can't replace `str.split(",")` with `str = str.split(",")` because str.split(",") returns an array of strings (and therefore is not a void method).

Comment: Also, the while loop breaks as soon as a line is read from br1. It should probably break when nothing further can be read from br1.

Answer (score 1):

`str.split(",")` returns an array of strings that represent the pieces of the original string separated by `,`. The original string is unaffected by this method. So in your code, this line is not doing anything because you are ignoring the return value.

What you probably want is:

```
String[] parts = str.split(",");
// do something with the parts
```

**EDIT**

If you want to store the parts of the string in an array list:

```
String[] parts = str.split(",");
List listOfParts = Arrays.asList(parts);
```

**SECOND EDIT**

If you are trying to populate the array list with just the list of usernames:

```
while((str = br1.readLine()) != null){
    out.println(str);
    String[] parts = str.split(",");
    if(parts.length > 0) {
        userstr.add(parts[0]);
    }
}
```

Then, you can simplify this piece of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < userstr.size();){
    if(userT.equals(userstr.get(i))){
        out.print("cool");
    }
}
```

... by replacing it with this:

```
if(userstr.contains(user)) {
    out.print("cool");
}
```

Note that I compare against `user` which is a string, rather `userT` which appears to be a control.

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work for what I wanted to do. witch is store them in a array list

Comment: Edited to meet my undertanding of your requirements. Perhaps you can clarify your requirements?

Comment: Edited again based on improved understanding of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you uses "," as the argument to split(), your results might not be what you expect. If your string is "Sally, xyz", it will be split into "Sally" and " xyz".
Note the space in the second string.

What you probably want is to use "\s*,\s*" which translates to "any number of whitespace characters followed by a comma followed by any number of whitespace characters".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

String string = "this is the string to be split.";
ArrayList arrayList =  new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")));

This will add the splitted strings to arrayList.

Comment: nope i was not but thanks any way