# Gerator Image Random

Tags: android, image, random

I have is how to generate random images without repeating , as an example driving in an array 15 images and 7 images to send imageview but that are not repeated .

```
 int[] img={ R.drawable.ima1,R.drawable.ima2,R.drawable.ima3,R.drawable.ima4,R.drawable.ima5,R.drawable.ima6,R.drawable.ima7,R.drawable.ima8,R.drawable.ima9,R.drawable.ima10,R.drawable.ima11,R.drawable.ima12,R.drawable.ima13,R.drawable.ima14,R.drawable.ima15};
    int [] game= new int[7];
Random numerRan = new Random();
  for (int i=0;i<game.length ;i++)
           {
               int num= numerRan.nextInt(17);
               int x= img[num];
               game[i]=img[num];

           }

            img1.setImageResource(juego[0]);
            img2.setImageResource(juego[1]);
            img3.setImageResource(juego[2]);
            img4.setImageResource(juego[3]);
            img5.setImageResource(juego[4]);
            img6.setImageResource(juego[5]);
            img7.setImageResource(juego[6]);
            img8.setImageResource(juego[7]);
```

When I press the button control images to the score rando the position that was generated . The problem I have is that images are repeated.

I am using 2 arrangements the first is to save all the images and the second keep the random images that will assign imageview .

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I generates random images from the arrangement but some are repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an `int[]` array, use a `List<Integer>` instead, such as an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

That way, you'll be able to use [`Collections#shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)), which will have the desired effect. It'll randomly permute your list, in a non-repeating way. All you'll have to do later is to iterate on that `List`.

For more info, please refer to the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) documentation.

---

You can also convert that array to a `List`, like the following:

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(img);
```

For more info about that, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607289/converting-array-to-list-in-java).

Comment: thanks for your attention and support and me working properly.
Use a list < interger >
And then it was only agrege elements generate a method to shuffle .

Comment: public static void shuffle(List<Integer> array)
    {
        int tam= array.size();

            for(int i= 0 ; i < tam ; i++){
                int s = i+(int)(Math.random()*(tam-i));
                Integer temp = array.get(s);
                array.set(s, array.get(i));
                array.set(i, temp);

            }
    }