# I am trying to use "sort" method but I am getting an error

Tags: java

Below is the start of a method I am trying to write. But java doesn't like my use of `Arrays.sort` method

It says that I have an,

> Incompatible type: required int[], found void.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
static String [] findSpace(int lengthOfName1, int lengthOfName2, int lengthOfName3){
        String [] space = {":", ":", ":"};
        int [] lengthOfName = {0,0,0};
        int [] lengthOfNameSorted = {0, 0, 0};
        lengthOfName[0] = lengthOfName1; lengthOfName[1] = lengthOfName2; lengthOfName[2] = lengthOfName3;
        lengthOfNameSorted = Arrays.sort(lengthOfName);
```

Comment: The return type of `Arrays.sort()` is `void`, you can't assign it.  It sorts the given array in place.

Comment: Read the documentation (and examples) for how to use API / methods..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [alex440](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384044/alex440) and [markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338547/markspace) have already mentioned, the Java method `Arrays.sort()` is of type `void`, so it does not return a value as you'll find in [the oracle spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) for your specific case of `Arrays.sort(int[])`.

That being said, if you can't think of any compelling reason to have both of the arrays in the code you provided, you might just remove the `lengthOfNameSorted` array all together since you're already sorting `lengthOfName`.

Comment: thanks. I do have a compelling reason, as I will be comparing the two arrays.  I am really just trying to find the max of a given array. I was using the sort method so cause I know I can just refer to the last item of the sorted array to find the max. I looked for a max method online but didn't find any with method and clear description of how to use it. Do you know of any such method?

Comment: As far as I can remember, in Java there is no `max()` method for Arrays. There _is_, however, a `Collections.max()` method for Collection types. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2607335/9542960) is pretty straight forward and should get you pointed in the right direction. A quick search for Java Collections `.max()` method should fill in any gaps. If you're only going to be working with arrays of 3 elements, then the Collections route may be overkill as there are simpler ways to find the maximum of 3 items in just a few lines of code.

Comment: thanks. ya, i know i can create a loop to essentially duplicate a max function, but I am learning java and I am trying to get my self familiar with the built-in functions of java.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.sort() returns void. It sorts the array in-place, hence destroying the initial order.

Make sure that's what you need.

You can use

```
int[] lengthOfNameSorted = Arrays.copyOf(lengthOfName, lengthOfName.length);
Arrays.sort(lengthOfNameSorted);
```

If you really need a sorted copy of an array.

I would generally prefer using

```
 IntStream.of(lengthOfName).sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

unless the list is too big so that the memory and performance overhead of boxing is not negligible.

Comment: Thanks. I am really just trying to find the max of a given array. I was using the sort method so cause I know I can just refer to the last item of the sorted array to find the max. I looked for a max method online  but didn't find any with method and clear description of how to use it. Do you know of any such method?

Comment: @jay You don't need sort, which is O(nlogn), to find the max, which is O(n). You can use Arrays.stream(lengthOfName).max().getAsInt()