# How to solve this ArrayList issue?

Tags: java, arrays

I have searched around the internet and what I am doing seems to be the standard conversion operation, but it still tells me:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.util.List<T>)'
```

I also have no issues with String array conversions when done in same way. This is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 10, 1, 30, 50, 30};
        ArrayList<Integer>  arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(arrList);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you including both import `java.util.ArrayList` and `import java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: The element type must be the same : `Integer` vs `int`  .

Comment: Note that since there's not auto boxing for primitive arrays `Arrays.asList(arr)` will create a `List<int[]>` instead of a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting array to list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607289/converting-array-to-list-in-java)

Comment: On my machine I'm using Java's 8 (target compatibility 1.8) and it compiles without a problem, so maybe the solution for your case is to upgrade your target to the newer Java's version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Integer[] arr = {1, 10, 1, 30, 50, 30};
    ArrayList<Integer>  arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    System.out.println(arrList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since there's not auto boxing for primitive arrays `Arrays.asList(arr)` will create a `List<int[]>` instead of a `List<Integer>`.

If you want to convert that array to a `List<Integer>` try this:

```
//instead of boxed() you could use one of the mapToXX methods 
List<Integer>  arrList = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Integer>` constructor takes Integer as an **object** not a primitive array.
you don't have issues with Strings since Strings are already reference type (Objects).
All you need to do is to create the array `arr` as Integer.

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[] {1, 10, 1, 30, 50, 30};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will help you.

```
        int[] arr = {1, 10, 1, 30, 50, 30};
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = IntStream.of(arr)
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        System.out.println(arrList);
```