# The code is not working for some instances while its working fine for others

Tags: java, datetime, exception

The question is as follows: Define a class MyDate (day, month, year) with methods to accept and display a MyDate object. Accept date as dd, mm, yyyy. Throw user defined exception "InvalidDateException" if the date is invalid. Examples of invalid dates:

```
12 15 2015
31 6 1990
29 2 2001
```

I wrote the following code but its not working in some instances. Please assist!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;

class InvalidDateException extends Exception
{}

class MyDate 
{
    int day,month,year;
    
    void accept()
    {   
        try
        {  
            Scanner S= new Scanner(System.in);
            int d,m,y;
            System.out.println("\nEnter day \nExample: 12 25 30  =>");
            d=S.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\nEnter month \nExample: 2 6 12  =>");
            m=S.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\nEnter year \nExample: 2012 2025 1930  =>");
            y=S.nextInt();
            //display();                                 for testing porposes
            //System.out.println(valid(d,m,y));          for testing porposes
            if(valid(d,m,y))
            {
                day=d;
                month=m;
                year=y;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidDateException();
            }
         }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("InvalidDateException");
        }
    }
    
    boolean valid(int d,int m,int y)
    {
        int []m31=new int[]{1,3,5,7,8,10,12};
        int []m30=new int[]{4,6,9,11};
                //System.out.println("\n\t\t"+d+m+y);            for testing porposes
        if(Arrays.asList(m31).contains(m) && d<=31)
        {
            
            return true;
        }
        else if(Arrays.asList(m30).contains(m) && d<=30)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(y%4==0 && d<=29)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(y%4!=0 && d<=28)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("DAY-MONTH-YEAR :: "+day+"-"+month+"-"+year);
    }
    
}


class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyDate date= new MyDate();
        date.accept();
        date.display();
    }
}
```

While I have resolved the other issues, the program seems to not work for days above 29.

[Its showing valid if day is below 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUxv3.jpg)

[And invalid for day above 29 changing month or year has no affect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WWX4.jpg)

Comment: I notice you're catching all exceptions - are you sure it's an `InvalidDateException` that's getting thrown? In general `catch(Exception E)` is a dangerous line of code to write, because it can obfuscate unexpected errors

Comment: Yeap, just comment out the try/catch block and let it explode, see what is the error :) and if you don't figure out post the stack trace here in your question

Comment: Could you, please, include the sample runs as text in the question body? You may edit the question to do that.

Comment: Make your life easier: `List<Integer> m31 = List.of(1,3,5,7,8,10,12);` then you can `if (m31.contains(m))`

Comment: Since `m31` and `m30` have elements in ascending order, can `Arrays.binarySearch(m31, m) >= 0` be substituted for `Arrays.asList(m31).contains(m)` ?

Comment: there was another instance that came across when I was making changes: " 12 13 2000" this would've returned true as no condition was placed in else if(y%4==0 && d<=29) thus the appropriate change for it was else if(m==2 && y%4==0 && d<=29) same for else if(y%4!=0 && d<=28) => else if(m==2 && y%4!=0 && d<=28)

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(m31)` is a list of one array, not an array converted to a list. (I hate it too.)

I'm not entirely clear why, but `List<T>::contains` takes an `Object`, not a `T`, so this type checked. Really seems like it shouldn't have.

It's a type inferenence thing, I think - if you just declare your arrays as `Integer[]` rather than `int[]` it works.

See [Converting array to list in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607289/converting-array-to-list-in-java) for more info.