# How can I create a java.sql.Array of Strings?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jdbc

I have:

```java
String[] time = {"22:22:22","22:22:23"};
Array asd = null; // This should have the same strings as time
```

How can I create an [`java.sql.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Array.html) containing the given `time` values, i.e. something like `asd = time`?

Comment: Looks like he refers to java.sql.Array. I have retagged.

Comment: Edit your question to increase it's clarity. Not much info for people to go on in answering.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL.  Retagged.

Comment: @BobJarvis This has everything to do with SQL, retagged...

Comment: @BobJarvis Please keep the SQL and JDBC tags. Even though the OP didn't state it explicitly in the question, some of his comments clearly shows that the question _is_ actually related to SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108679/how-do-i-cast-from-string-to-array/4109407#comment4423786_4108729

Answer (score 23):

I assume that what you actually need is a [`java.sql.Array`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html), since you mention jdbc and [`setArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray%28int,%20java.sql.Array%29) in some of your comments.

Three options:

1. Try [`Connection.createArrayOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29). This might or might not be available, depending on the JDBC driver you are using.
2. Write your own class that implements `java.sql.Array`. Here is [an example](http://tech.valgog.com/2009/02/passing-arrays-to-postgresql-database.html) for PostgreSQL.
3. Some implementations, such as [Oracle's](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oraarr.htm), provide utility methods to work with arrays. Check the documentation of your JDBC driver.

Comment: In the example of PostgreSQL, there is no method where we can pass the List or Arrays to get the java.sql.Array.

Answer (score 5):

The `Array` class is not an actual array.  Instead it is a helper class that has static methods to help with arrays.

You may be looking to use `ArrayList` or something like it.  You could use it using `List<String> asd = Arrays.asList(time)`

Comment: The problem is that i want to use a method in the jdbc driver framework that inserts arrays into sql databases this method is something like setArray(int arg0, Array arg1) and it only acepts the Array array type what should i do i tried another array types including arralist and nothing is working

Comment: anyone that can help me?

Comment: What method are you trying to use?

Comment: Yes, Array has a set of static methods, so I was suggesting using Arrays.asList instead.  But it now looks like he was trying to use java.sql.Arrays, so my answer does not apply.  @Grodriguez seems to have the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

`Array` is an interface, not a class. Are you referring to `ArrayList`?!

Here is your answer: [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java)

`new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array))`

Comment: The problem is that i want to use a method in the jdbc driver framework that inserts arrays into sql databases this method is something like setArray(int arg0, Array arg1) and it only acepts the Array array type what should i do i tried another array types including arralist and nothing is working

Comment: What error do you get when you give it a string array? What error you get when you give it an ArrayList?