# Transform array to list

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have the following fragment of code:

```
public void doSomething() {
  float array[] = new float[2];
  array[0] = (float) 0.0;
  array[1] = (float) 1.2;
  someMethod(array);
}

public void someMethod(Object value) {
   //need to convert value to List<Float>
}
```

As you can see above I want to convert the value variable which is an array (but passed as an Object) to List.
I tried the following as suggested here: [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java)

```
    new ArrayList<Float> (Arrays.asList(value));
```

however, it does not compile.

Any hints?

Comment: Whenever a question involves a compile error, it's helpful to include that error message, just like it's helpful to show the stacktrace for runtime errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public void someMethod(Object value) {
    float[] array = (float[]) value;
    List<Float> result = new ArrayList<Float>(array.length);
    for (float f : array) {
        result.add(Float.valueOf(f));
    }
    // ...
}
```

I don't know why you're not defining the value argument as a `float[]` rather than an `Object`, though.

Comment: +1 You don't need the Float.valueOf, result.add(f) will work because it's being autoboxed.

Comment: Indeed. But when I answer a question over a primitive vs. object problem, I prefer making the transformation explicit, to avoid confusing the OP even more. The generated byte code should be exactly the same.

Comment: It is indeed exactly the same.

Comment: I can't use float[] instead of Object as the method comes from 3rd party API.

Answer (score 4):

[Updated per JB Nizet's correction.]
If you use Float instead of float for the array, it will work *if the compiler knows that `value` is an array* - which it doesn't.  Add a cast:

```
new ArrayList<Float> (Arrays.asList((Float[])value));
```

or just change the parameter type of `value` to Float[], and leave out the cast.

Comment: Now we have ClassCastException: [F cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Float

Comment: @Matthew - note first line - _If you use Float instead of float for the array_.  If it wasn't clear, I meant that it should be declared as: `Float[] array = new Float[2];`

Comment: @Ed but that wasn't the original problem.

Comment: @Matthew - I see you've put the same comment on other answers.  You're making an assumption that the OP can't or doesn't want to change the type.  I'm assuming he can and doesn't care which it is.  I understand that in general, it's important to stick to the premises of the original question, but I think this is overkill.  You might consider asking the OP, if you really think it's likely that he cares.

Comment: @Ed. I'm just pointing out that it doesn't fulfil the original questions. It's perfectly acceptable for you to point out that he can change the array.

Comment: Matthew, the question asks for hints about how to make the given example code compile.  It doesn't state what part of that code that the solution must or must not change in order to make it compile.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to view a `float[]` as a `List<Float>` then Guava's `Floats.asList` method will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Change `float` to `Float` since `Arrays.asList(T...a)` cannot return a `List<float>` because a Java primitive type cannot be passed as an argument to a generic type.

```
public void doSomething() {
    Float array[] = new Float[2];
    array[0] = 0.0f;
    array[1] = 1.2f;
    someMethod(array);
}

public void someMethod(Object value) {
    List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float> (Arrays.asList((Float[])value));
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

prints

```
[0.0, 1.2]
```