# How to implement vector of arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, vector, arraylist

I want to have a resizable structure in Java to keep one dimension-arrays or vectors of type double. What is the best way to do?

Is it possible to pass an array as parameter to an Arraylist? May be to a Vector?

If not what is a quite reasonable solution?

After all, based on the proposed implementation, what is the most effective way to gain values from the structure and to use them on calculations (adding arrays, multiply arrays ,etc).

Comment: why you are looking for vector, are you working on synchronised objects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java

Comment: Yes, you can certainly have `List<double[]> myList = new ArrayList<double[]>();` I don;t see anything inherently wrong with that. If you need a list of arrays, then you need a list of arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With generics, you can pass any `type` which is a sub-class of `java.lang.Object.` (Java primitive types are not sub-class of `java.lang.Objec`t)

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> doubles=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
//or
Vector<Double> doubles=new ArrayList<Double>();
```

and of course you can pass array object.

```
ArrayList<String[]> obj=new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an ArrayList<Double>  however you may find that [TDoubleArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TDoubleArrayList.html) is more efficient as this wraps a `double[]`

Answer (score 1):

Create an ArrayList holding references to other ArrayLists, like so:

```
List<List<Double>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();

List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();

listOfLists.add(doubleList);
```

You should not create a List of arrays, as Collections and arrays don't mix very well.

**EDIT**

Vector is effectively deprecated. Use ArrayList instead.

Comment: I disagree about the mixing of Collections and arrays

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a [ListMultmap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html)

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Double> listOfLists;
```

The integer key would be your index (0, 1, 2, etc). This structure takes care of creating the inner lists for you. It will check if a list already exists at an index and create prior to the insert if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for matrices? If so, look at [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) or [CERN Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/package-summary.html), rather than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have `List<List<Double>>` or `List<Double[]>`.

You should use the more modern `List/ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.

The most effective choice depends on what exactly you want to do with it, but initially, you should look at the implementations of the [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface

Answer (score 0):

Java's arrays *are* objects, so anywhere you can pass an `Object`, you can pass an array. An `ArrayList` is ideal for building an ordered sequence of arrays; don't use `Vector` unless you've got an old API that you're coding to (or you need the exact type of synchronization implemented by it; you probably don't want that).

Internally, an `ArrayList` contains an array of `Object` references.

If you're doing rectangular matrices or sparse arrays, there can be better ways of implementing things. Matrices incur less overhead if implemented with a single array rather than an array of arrays (or worse, an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s) but you have to do more work to hide the fact. Sparse arrays are better done as a variation on a `Map` (itself a somewhat costly thing, but you save by being able to omit much storage).