# From which library to include inline List creation?

Tags: java

I find myself re-implementing List creation method. But I'm sure that it is already implemented in some widely used library (if not in java itself). So my question is: Which useful library to include, to get functionality of following code:

```
public static <T> List<T> buildList(T... args) {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T arg : args)
    {
        list.add(arg);
    }
    return list;
}
```

EDIT: Already found what i was looking for: http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/
I just import statically:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
```

and use:

```
methodThatTakesArray(newArrayList("fst", "snd", "lst"));
```

Comment: When Java and Collections are concerned, google guava have to be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

[java.util.Arrays#asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I did consider that, but its not as convenient :(

Comment: @Lauri Why isn't it? It does the same thing you asked. If you need a dynamic-sized list, you can: `list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myArray))`

Comment: I don't want to create array. Sure it's not _that_hard_ but it's unnecessary. Sure my method could work on array, but it also works on varargs AND that is what I'm after. Anyway, i found solution, check my original posts' edit.

Answer (score 0):

A short hand to convert arrays to arraylist.

```
ArrayList<T> arraylist = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(array))
```

Check this out, [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java)