# How to create a new ArrayList containing all elements from an int[] arrary?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my code so far. I'm kind of new with ArrayLists.

```
public void fill(int []arr){
   ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Thats all I have so far. I don't know how to put all of the elements from `int[] arr` into the new `ArrayList`. The elements should be in order as well.

Comment: You should take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java). I think this is exactly what you need. Hope it helps

Comment: With `intList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));` though this sounds suspiciously like homework.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java

Comment: @user1261935 - If this is homework, it should tagged as such.

Comment: If you made any progress or solved the problem you could accept an answer as well :)

Answer (score 3):

If you had an array of objects, you could use Arrays.asList ..., but with primitives, you'll have to loop through the array and add each element to the arraylist individually.

```
for (int i : arr) {
    intList.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(myIntArray);
```

Otherwise, you will need to use a loop and iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
public void fill(int []arr){
   ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      intList.add(arr[i])
   }
}
```

Also refer to the [ArrayList JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).