# Creating a List<string> containing a single string N times

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to construct a list of type `List<string>` which contains a single string `N` times without using a loop? Something similar to `String(char c, int count)` but instead for List of strings.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "str", "str", "str", ..... N times };
```

Comment: What is wrong using a loop?

Comment: this is interesting, but can you also give some context on why you need that and how you plan to use it? Just that we can suggest you a good solution of your problem without being framed by your suggested approach :)

Comment: doing something repitive without using a loop is like juggling without using your arms. Why can't you use a loop construct?

Comment: You can not insert without loop you can insert in it other with InsertRange.

Comment: if you can create array, then you can create list of string from the array.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java

Comment: @rene why use a loop when Enumerrable.Repeat is created specifically for a situation like this?

Comment: @RuneFS Isn't that an highlevel contruct over a loop? In my reasoning I guess the OP want to rule out the msil containing a branch statement. But maybe that is just the purist in me... :)

Comment: @rene there's definitively going to be a branch or two in there but he said "loop" and not "loops or conditions" if he worried about branches then if,?:,switch,goto,continue,break and possibly a fwe other should have been banned as well

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `Repeat()`:

```
List<String> l = Enumerable.Repeat<String>("foo", 100).ToList<String>();
```

It will still use a loop of course, but now you don't "see" it.

Comment: its already there in CLR. But less used method. short and sweet to repeat :)

Comment: Repeat doesn't need to be implemented with a loop. It could be recursive, use the enumerator block rewrite (which is rewritten to a state machine), use labels and goto's etc

Comment: @RuneFS: Can you give me a valid definition of "loop"? If you work with goto/label you still have a "loop" I would say. I don't know if it's correct, but I would define a "loop" (in programming) as a pattern used to `repeat` (the execution of) a piece of code. And if you do something wrong with recursion, you usually get an endless "loop", don't you?

Comment: @igrimpe usually that's calle diteration and it's a endless recursion.
To me if that's the definition of a loop the you could also say that when coding in C# you are actually coding in machine code because the end result is machine code. So asking how you can repeat something with out repeating (your definition of a loop) doesn't really make sense does it? In a given context I'd agree with your definition. Here however I believe `loop` is short hand of loop construct (`for`,`foreach`, `do`, `while`) because then there's still sense in the question

Comment: @RuneFS: We could discuss this endless (which SO dislikes), but you are right in one thing: The question (How can I loop without looping) doesn't make sense. I understand the question more as "how can I make it look NICE?". And LINQ (imho) looks nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  list.add("str");
}
```