# How can I convert an int array to an arraylist?

Tags: java

Example I have a initialized an int array like this:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Is it possible to make this an arraylist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create ArrayList (ArrayList<T>) from array (T\[\]) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `array` is of type `int[]` and not `Integer[]`, [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) is of no help.

Here is one way that will work:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int el : array) {
   list.add(el);
}
```

If the type of `array` can be changed to `Integer[]`, things get simpler:

```
Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

This gives a list, but not an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). What you get is *similar* to an `ArrayList`, but is fixed-size. If that's an issue, you could use:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: I changed the array into Integer[] but it says "type List does not take parameters" what does that mean? Is something wrong with the way I wrote it?

Comment: @progRookie: You've probably imported `java.awt.List` instead of `java.util.List`.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};   
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    myArrayList.add(array[i]);
}
```

hope this helps you...

Comment: Use your IDE to code and copy/paste it here. This will avoid answers with compiler errors, such as yours.