# Changing an Array to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am attempting to change the following array line into an ArrayList that will function the same way:

```
private String[] books = new String[5];
```

I changed it to this but it is not functioning properly:

```
private ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(books))
```

I thought this was how an ArrayList was created

Comment: Could you add a language tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/157944/1065197)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create it like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> booksList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(books));
```

`new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(books))` is the part which is turning your array into an `ArrayList`.

You could also do:

```
private List<String> booksList = Arrays.asList(books);
```

If the fact that it is an `ArrayList` doesn't matter.

Comment: I keep getting errors that `ArrayList` cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Dingles make sure you have imported the right classes from the right packages. You should have `package your.package.name; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Arrays; (...)` at the top of your file.

Comment: Ahhh I forgot the `import java.util.Arrays` package.

Answer (score 0):

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

```
new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array))
```

*** new

Comment: Instead of adding an answer pointing to an existing Q/A, flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: will do.. kind of new to SO