# Clear properly a java arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a 2d ArrayList from a 2d array. Actually I ve got a temp ArrayListand I parse it to my 2d ArrayList in for loop. I am trying to find  the correct way to clear this temp ArrayList in order to pass every time, the correct values to mags ArrayList.

```
   for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < gaborWavelet.length; i++) {
                temp.clear();   
                for (int j = 0; j < gaborWavelet[0].length; j++) {
                    sum = gaborWavelet[i][j][m][n][0] / (M * N);
                    temp.add((int) (sum * 170));                
                }
                mags.add(temp);             
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above code only the final indexed-i it is passed in the temp m*n*i times.

EDIT:

```
        for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < gaborWavelet.length; i++) {
                ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
                for (int j = 0; j < gaborWavelet[0].length; j++) {
                    sum = gaborWavelet[i][j][m][n][0] / (M * N);
                    temp.add((int) (sum * 170));                
                }
                mags.add(temp);             
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(mags.get(200));
    System.out.println(mags.get(0));
```

If the above is what you mean, I am getting the same issue here.

Comment: 2D ArrayList is a code smell IMHO

Comment: Create an instance of your `temp` arrayList inside the `for(int i ..)` loop. On a different note, 4 nested loop!?

Comment: ArrayList.clear(). If that doesn't answer your question, what's your question?

Comment: You don't want to clear temp list it in each loop. Instead create new lists for each "row" and add them to your `mags`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `temp.clear()` do `temp = new ArrayList()`. With your code in mags will be the same ArrayList added multiple times.

And read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t) on how to create `ArrayList` from array