# How to add bitmap array to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, bitmap

I have a Bitmap array in android, now I need to add this array to an ArrayList. I did this like

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bmp_images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(Arrays.asList(bmp));
```

But it showing an error **The constructor ArrayList(List) is undefined**

where **bmp** is the Bitmap array. What should i do please someone help me to fix this

Comment: post bmp declaration...

Comment: Store the bitmap on your device and then add the path to the list. Why do you want bitmap in a list?

Comment: @GopalRao sorry its just a mistake about the bitmap array declaration

Comment: I figured. The error message is interesting, though. What was the mistake you were making?

Comment: @drewmore This error is shown if `bmp` is an array of something other than `Bitmap`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create ArrayList (ArrayList<T>) from array (T\[\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

Comment: @Apoorv that's what I thought was the case, but usually the exception thrown in that complains about being unable to do the conversion, not the constructor being undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this can help you.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bmp_images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
for(int i = 0; i < bmp.length ;i++ ){
     bmp_images.add(bmp[i]);
}
```

Comment: so whats wrong with `ArrayList<Bitmap> bmp_images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(Arrays.asList(bmp));`???

Comment: -1 Is this really necessary? The code OP posted is good Java. Is there a concrete reason it can't work on Android? If so, that should be part of your answer. If not, I would *never* recommend using a loop where there is a library function available, and neither should you.

Comment: @GopalRaonothing wrong with it thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can add every single item one by one or you can consider using [Collections.addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use (assuming `bmp` is `Bitmap[]`)

```
List<Bitmap> bmp_images = Arrays.asList(bmp);
```

And there is no need for creating a copy of this collection (depending on your needs)

But it seems you have some problems with declarations of `bmp` array, so inspect that part.