# Converting Object[] to ArrayList<V>[] in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

The following code throws an ClassCastException:

```
ArrayList<V>[] table = (ArrayList<V>[]) new Object[tableSize];
```

How can I create an Array of ArrayList if this doesn't work?

EDIT:

To be shure everybody understands the problem. I need an Array that contains multiple ArrayLists.

EDIT2:

tableSize is an int.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create ArrayList (ArrayList<T>) from array (T\[\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

Comment: Of course it throws an exception. An array is NOT a list, and an Object list is NOT a V class. In fact, what is `V`? Is it a template parameter?

Comment: Can You edit your question, and add the type of `table` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: OK, here is what you can do:

```
ArrayList<String>[] table = new ArrayList[tableSize];
```

It compiles and works on Java 8 i'm using.

Comment: Ah, last version you had <> between ArrayList and tablesize. This works. Thanks.

Comment: And it works with `List<String>[] table = new List[tableSize];` too. This is truly interesting.

Comment: Interestion point, `List` is an interface, but can make an array of interfaces, no problem.

Answer (score -1):

In case of Java you can not create new instance of array that type is generic.

`T[] array = new T[size];` - cause compile error `Cannot create a generic array of T`.

The same error will be present when you will try to use it

`ArrayList<T>[] array = new ArrayList<T>[size];`

With the same reason. The Java runtime does not know what is `T` after compilation therefor will not be able to allocate valid memory space.

To pass this issue you have following options:

- Remove the generic type and use a raw.

`ArrayList[] array =new ArrayList[size];`

- Use list of a list

`List<List<T>> list = new ArrayList<List<T>>();`

Answer (score -1):

Not the smoothest way to do it But if I got your question correctly something like this should do the trick:

```
int tableSize = 2;
Collection<String> listWithItems = new ArrayList<>();
listWithItems.add("Foo");
listWithItems.add("Bar");    

Collection<Collection<String>> listOfList = new ArrayList<>();
listOfList.add(listWithItems);    

Object[] array = listOfList.toArray(new Object[tableSize]);    

System.out.println("Col: " + listOfList);
System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
```

Print out is:

```
Col: [[Foo, Bar]]
Array: [[Foo, Bar], null]
```

Short example without extra "fluff" to get the inital array:

```
Object[] theArrayOfLists = new ArrayList<List<SomeClass>>().toArray(new Object[tableSize]);
```