# Java. Should I use a list or an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, compare, directory

I am using java 7 but could upgrade to 8 if deemed worthwhile.

I am creating a program to compare files in 2 folders.

I am using Files.newDirectoryStream to extract the file data, although i have still to work out how to do that recursively, but I'm sure that should not be too difficult.

So to the point, I will do the compare and then add missing items so they are in sync.
This means I will need to store:

1) the name & 
2) the path

Therefore I will need to use something to do this.  I know I can do it with an Array[][].  But is this the best way to do this, or are lists more efficient.

I imagine the largest folder to hold 200 files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just use a List, it is likely to be easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create ArrayList (ArrayList<T>) from array (T\[\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ArrayList<File>` which can be seen as a "Wrapper around plain arrays" (for the sake of simplicity and understanding). As each element in the List will be of type `File`, you will already have access to the path and name of the file and do not need to store them seperatly.

Of course the ArrayList has a bit more overhead then using simple arrays, but if you expect the largest amount to be 200 files, it's not a big deal and nothing to worry about. Except you run your program on your calculator ;)

If you can, you should first fetch the amount of files in your current working directory and use that number as initial size for the List:

```
int numberOfFiles = fetchFileCount(directory);
ArrayList<File> currentFiles = new ArrayList<>(numberOfFiles);
```

Comment: I was using the array with the path type, but I'll look into using file to get out the filename and path. Thanks