# How to create a list of doubles out of an array of doubles

Tags: java, arrays, list, double

First off, I want to say that I know this has been asked before at the following location (among others), but I have not had any success with the answers there:

[Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
double[] FFTMagnitudeArray = processAudio.processFFT(audioData);


List<Double> FFTMagnitudeList = Arrays.asList(FFTMagnitudeArray);


audioData.setProperty("FFTMagnitudeList", FFTMagnitudeList);
```

However, I get the error:

```
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<double[]> to List<Double>"
```

This makes no sense to me, as I thought the List was necessary and the Array.asList(double[]) would return a list of Double, not double[]. I have also tried the following, to no avail:

```
List<Double> FFTMagnitudeList = new ArrayList<Double>();
FFTMagnitudeList.addAll(Arrays.asList(FFTMagnitudeArray));


List<Double> FFTMagnitudeList = new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(FFTMagnitudeArray));
```

And I keep getting the same error.

So how do I create the List?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your method to return the object wrapper array type.

```
Double[] FFTMagnitudeArray = processAudio.processFFT(audioData);
List<Double> FFTMagnitudeList = Arrays.asList(FFTMagnitudeArray);
```

Or you'll have to manually copy from the primitive to the wrapper type (for the List).

```
double[] FFTMagnitudeArray = processAudio.processFFT(audioData);
List<Double> FFTMagnitudeList = new ArrayList<>(FFTMagnitudeArray.length);
for (double val : FFTMagnitudeArray) {
  FFTMagnitudeList.add(val);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `double` type is a primitive type and not an object. `Arrays.asList` expects an array of objects. When you pass the array of `double` elements to the method, and since arrays are considered as objects, the method would read the argument as an array of the `double[]` object type.

You can have the array element set the `Double` wrapper type.

```
Double[] FFTMagnitudeArray = processAudio.processFFT(audioData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8:

```
List<Double> FFTMagnitudeList = Arrays.stream(FFTMagnitudeArray).mapToObj(Double::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This creates a `DoubleStream` (a stream of the primitive type `double`) out of the array, uses a mapping which converts each `double` to `Double` (using `Double.valueOf()`), and then collects the resulting stream of `Double` into an `ArrayList`.