# Putting arrays in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list

Probably a very stupid question, but how can I put an array into an ArrayList?

Example:

```
String[] strings = {"ex","okay",};
ArrayList<String> stringslist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now how do I put everything in strings, into stringlist?

Comment: Collections.addAll(stringslist,strings)

Comment: @christopher Depends on if OP wants an `ArrayList` or `Arrays.ArrayList`, or if they want an `ArrayList<String[]`, hard to say as written

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Arrays.asList() function.

```
String[] strings = {"ex","okay",};

ArrayList newStringslist = new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(strings))
```

[Tutorials-Point Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_aslist.htm)

Also - [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

Comment: You should not use raw types. Also, it would be better to use `List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strings));` because the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is not an `ArrayList` and doesn't let you add/remove elements from that list.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Ok, got it. will fix

Comment: `Arrays.asList` will not return `java.util.ArrayList` but `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`.

Comment: @Pshemo - Hmm, interesting. ok I'll fix thanks!!

Comment: @Coffee You already did.

Answer (score -1):

`new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array))` -- JAVA

per answer at [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)