# How to know if List.remove() is "Unsupported"?

Tags: java, list, unsupportedoperation

I have this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] values = { "yes", "no"};
        List<String> aa = Arrays.asList(values);
        System.out.println(aa.getClass().getName());
        aa.remove(0);
    }

}
```

It gives:

```
$ java ListTest 
java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at ListTest.main(ListTest.java:12)
```

Question: I understand why I am getting this exception. It is because the `ArrayList` class from inside `Arrays.java` is being used which does not have a `remove()` method. My question is how can someone(any user, like me) know before using that the `List` they received that it does not contain a `remove` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to know. All of the [`List<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) methods that change the list are listed as optional. A subclass can implement them or not. Unfortunately the API does not include a method like `isReadOnly()`, so there's no way to check if these methods will throw exceptions without calling them.

It is the responsibility of the owner of the read-only list not to pass it to methods that will try to change it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the Interface is properly implemented, writing a remove method that throws an Exception is completely legal. So, no you won't know until it breaks... That is when Javadoc comes handy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class ListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] values = { "yes", "no"};
        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values));
        System.out.println(aa.getClass().getName());
        aa.remove(0);
  }
}
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t) is a very good explanation for your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you forget "String" inside <> here :         `List<String> aa = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values));`

Comment: No no. That is `diamond inferance`. Allows only in Java 7 and higher. You can use it as both ways if you java version is higher than 7. Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList` returns a `List` wrapper for an `array`. This wrapper has a fixed size and is directly backed by the `array` hence there can't be modify methods. So better to keep in mind that else i am not sure how to know it because at least compile time you will not get an error .

If you want to get a Collection from a array to modify you can use

```
Collection c = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(values));
```

Comment: The OP knows this. The question was whether or not there was any way to detect this lack of implementation without knowing the concrete type of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well what u have done that is directly return like this. ex. array in easy way something like this String array[] means its returning array now tell me is there anyway to remove that element from that i mean from the array? that is belongs from list only

one possible way is .

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class ListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] values = { "yes", "no"};
        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values)); // this will return arraylist (according that u wanted).
        System.out.println(aa.getClass().getName());
        aa.remove(0); // removes element as of list interface have remove method.
  }
}
```