# Java, error creating ArrayList from fixed array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Using Java 1.8, when I do the following:

```
final int[] weights = { 812, 123, 442, 321, 322, 242, 555 };
final ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
for(int i : weights)
{
    list.add(i);
}
```

using that ArrayList works as expected. However, if I do this:

```
final int[] weights = { 812, 123, 442, 321, 322, 242, 555 };
final ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(weights));
```

using the ArrayList in the exact same way as for the above, I get

```
ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

From here [Create ArrayList from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t) it seems to me as what I am doing in the second case is correct, so why do I get the exception?

It should also be noted that NB 8 warns me that "Confusing primitive array passed to vararg method" for the second instantiation of ArrayList above. Anyone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: There is no autoboxing for `int[]` to `Integer[]`. Also [generics don't support primitive types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2721546/1393766) so `T` in `Arrays.asList(T...)` represents `int[]` not `Integer` which means that it will return `List<int[]>` not `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Try specifying the data type of your arraylist ==>>. Arraylist<integer>

Comment: @NullSoulException there is no `<integer>` in Java. Also there is no `<int>` because generics don't support primitive types. Also there is no point in explicitly using `<Integer>` to store `<int[]>`.