# No method to get stream of byte array

Tags: java, java-8

I want to get stream of byte array but I came to know that [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) does not have method to get stream of byte array.

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[100];
Arrays.stream(byteArr);//Compile time error
```

My questions,

- Why this feature is not supported ?
- How can I get Stream of byte array ?

NOTE : I know I can use `Byte[]` instead of `byte[]` but that does not answer my question.

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888429/how-can-i-create-a-stream-from-an-array

Comment: @JohnKuhns the link you gave is fr a stream of objects. The OP wants a stream of primitive bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only 3 types of primitive streams: IntStream, LongStream and DoubleStream.

So, the closest you can have is an IntStream, where each byte in your array is promoted to an int.

AFAIK, the simplest way to build one from a byte array is

```
    IntStream.Builder builder = IntStream.builder();
    for (byte b : byteArray) {
        builder.accept(b);
    }
    IntStream stream = builder.build();
```

EDIT: [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829571/assylias) suggests another, shorter way:

```
IntStream stream = IntStream.range(0, byteArr.length)
                            .map(i -> byteArray[i]);
```

Comment: You can also use `IntStream.range(0, byteArr.length).map(i -> byteArr[i])`

Comment: @assylias: nice. Didn't think about that trick.