# Converting int array to char array

Tags: java, arrays, converters, primitive-types

Is it possible to `cast` an `int array` to a `char array`? If so - `how`?

---

I'm currently working on a project where I need to `create an char array` containing the `alphabet`. *My* current `code` creats an `int array` (which should be `converted` to an `char array` - **in one Line!**):

`return IntStream.range('a', 'z' + 1).toArray();`

Comment: If you want to convert a digit (0-9), you can add 48 to it and cast, or something like `Character.forDigit(a, 10)`;.

Comment: yes it is possible , just convert your number into 16 based number , consists of a-f and 0-9 :))

Comment: No, you can't cast `int[]` to `char[]`. Also, *your* current code doesn't work, so it doesn't matter how short it is. First rule of optimization: It has to work. Since Java 8 doesn't have a `CharStream`, you should do it with a normal `for` loop. It only takes 3 lines of code (4 with return statement), and it *works!*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, we’re missing a stream method to produce a char array. Maybe a whole CharStream class. In any case, no, you cannot cast between `int[]` and `char[]`.

In the meantime, it’s getting a long line, but it works:

```
    return IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z')
            .mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
            .collect(Collectors.joining())
            .toCharArray();
```

This gives a `char[]` containing

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! +1 becuase you arren't a "This wont work"- person :P

Comment: `IntStream.range('a', 'z' + 1)` can be replaced with `IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z')`

Comment: @Pshemo, thx, it may belong as a comment to the question (from where I took `IntStream.range('a', 'z' + 1)`), but in any case, it’s clearly more readable.

Comment: A downside to this solution is that a String object is created for each array element — this could be a performance / memory consideration for larger arrays.

Answer (score 2):

From **Java-11** and onwards , you can use `.mapToObj(Character::toString)` 
instead of `.mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))` , so your overall code boils down to :

```
return IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z')
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
        .toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep it one line then:

```
return IntStream.range('a', 'z' + 1).mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf((char) i)).toArray(Character[]::new);
```

This converts from `IntStream`, to `Stream<Character>`. Keep in mind chars and ints are essentially the same in terms of many calculations, so this step may be unnecessary (especially for comparisons).

**Edit:**

Fixed the above line to be functional, there is a better solution but I'm still trying to find it again. It currently returns a `Character[]` array.

Without the 1 line restriction it's simple to just remake the array, treating `a` as your 0 index.

```
char[] back = new char[('z' + 1) - 'a'];
IntStream.range('a', 'z' + 1).forEach(i -> back[i - 'a'] = (char) i);
return back;
```

Comment: that's what I'm talking about! The only problem is, that it returns an `object array` - how can I cast it to an char array? :3

Comment: i am not sure if its just my compiler but your solution leads to following error for me: Error: java: incompatible types: java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to char

Comment: No you're both correct, there's a better way I'll edit it in in just a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast int array to char array because there are absolutely different types.

There are 2 possible options:

1) create a char array and copy each value from int array
2) use generic lists or collections. You can simple use it for casting

Comment: @TheRealVira streams does it. not arrays

Comment: Just to keep the usage correct, @AlexKlimashevsky is correct, my answer is not doing a *cast*, but solving your problem by other means.

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky plus there is a way to get a stream from your array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888429/how-can-i-create-a-stream-from-an-array