# How to convert a LIst<> to Stream<List<>> in dart for flutter streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I accessed value from a field in FireStore but it's in a form of a list and I need to transform it to a Stream<List<>> to put in a streambuilder. How would I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: read [creating-streams](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a stream from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888429/how-can-i-create-a-stream-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the value using `get()` on a document reference you can use:

`Stream documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection').doc('ABC123').snapshots();`

You can use snapshots directly with your StreamBuilder:

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          ....
}
```