# JAVA 8 || The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Can anyone help me to find the root cause why I am getting these below error ?
The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int

Code Snippet :

```
int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
Stream.of(arr1).filter(num -> (num % 2) == 0).skip(1).limit(1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

[IDE highlighting error in code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCnqg.png)

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27888447/3558960) of the duplicate question has all the information you need, and then some.

Comment: you are supposed to use Arrays.stream() to stream array elements, not pass the array as a whole to the stream

Comment: `IntStream.of(...)` is another way.