# How to wrap up multiple byte arrays in such a way that it can be serialized and used over RMI

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, byte

I am creating a client/server RMI application and need to search for images on the server database and return to the client multiple images.

I immediately thought to do this `ArrayList<Byte []>arrayBytes = new ArrayList <Byte []>();` and `return arrayBytes`, I soon found that it is impossible.

Researched `ByteArrayOutputStream` but I do not think the support for what I'm trying to do ...

What alternative have for this?

Comment: Why can't you use `ArrayList<byte[]>`?

Comment: In my understanding, an array of bytes is the same as a byte array. Do I miss something?

Comment: Did you really mean an ArrayList of Bytes?

Comment: @aioobe That's an array of arrays, which isn't what he wants.

Comment: You need to be specific about what form is your input an what form is your output.  `byte[]` is something entirely different from `Byte[]` which is entirely different from `ArrayList<Byte>` which is entirely different from `ArrayList<Byte[]>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create ArrayList (ArrayList<T>) from array (T\[\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

Comment: @mbomb007, are you sure? He says he wants to return multiple images. That sounds like a `List<byte[]>` to me.

Comment: Hot Licks forgive me. Type is byte[]. It possible too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably after `ArrayList<byte[]>`. (You don't need to use `Byte` as component type for the array. `byte[]` is an `Object`.)

You can't do `new ArrayList<byte>[]`. Perhaps that's what confused you.