# Adding an array to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

So I created two arrays and an arrayList. Depending on the value of game(0 or 1), I want my arrayList to have all the values of one of my arrays. Here's what I've been trying

```
int[] americanBoard = {0,28,9,26,30,11,7,20,32,17,5,22,34,15,3,24,36,13,1,00,27,10,25,29,12,8,19,31,18,6,21,33,16,4,23,35,14,2};
int[] europeanBoard = {0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26};
ArrayList<Integer[]> board = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
(game>0? board.add(americanBoard): board.add(europeanBoard));
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your arrays type to `Integer` and then use the `Arrays.asList` method:

```
        Integer[] americanBoard = {0,28,9,26,30,11,7,20,32,17,5,22,34,15,3,24,36,13,1,00,27,10,25,29,12,8,19,31,18,6,21,33,16,4,23,35,14,2};
        Integer[] europeanBoard = {0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26};
        ArrayList<Integer> board = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList((game>0? americanBoard: europeanBoard)));
```

You can find more info regarding that method in [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.