# Using streams for a null-safe conversion from an array to list

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm looking for a succinct way to rewrite a piece of Java code so that it uses streams to convert an array to a list in a null-safe fashion.  Here's the original code:

```
public MailObject toMailObject(final String[] ccAddresses) {
    final MailObject mailObject = new MailObject();

    // line of code to be altered
    mailObject.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses == null 
        ? Collections.emptyList() : Arrays.asList(ccAddresses));

    // other necessary code

    return mailObject;
}
```

I've thought of doing something like this:

```
// psuedocode that obviously doesn't compile
Optional.ofNullable(ccAddresses).SOMETHING.orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

where SOMETHING would be along the lines of:

```
Arrays.stream(ints).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but I can't seem to get the syntax quite right.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122439/converting-array-to-list) was helpful but didn't exactly address my issue.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?  I feel like I'm close...

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Your original code seems succinct enough

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm curious as to the best way it can be done using streams.

Comment: `.map(Arrays::asList)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion, the code that you have so far is perfectly readable. I think using a `Stream` for something like this will just complicate things. If you still want to use a `Stream`, then something like the following would work:

```
mailObject.setCcAddresses(Stream.ofNullable(ccAddresses)
          .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
          .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()));
```

As you can see, this is a more unreadable, and I wouldn't recommend it over your simple ternary expression.

---

Your `Optional` solution is slightly more readable and would look like the following:

```
mailObject.setCcAddresses(Optional.ofNullable(ccAddresses)
          .map(Arrays::asList)
          .orElse(Collections.emptyList()));
```

Comment: `Stream.ofNullable` requires Java 9 and `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()` even requires Java 10. And when you’re using Java 9 or newer, you can likewise change the original code to `mailObject.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses == null? List.of(): List.of(ccAddresses));`, whose simplicity will highlight the silliness of using `Optional` or `Stream` here even more.

Comment: Good insight onto the Java versions that the first solution uses...and also into the `List.of()` possibility!  Between this and the full answer by @Jacob G. there are a lot of options here; thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You might use the `map` :

```
List<String> ccAddrs = Optional.ofNullable(ccAddress)
                               .map(Arrays::asList)
                               .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
```

Comment: I had wondered if the `.map()` method might be of use; thanks for the full usage in context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with my strong tested code:

Fixed type method:

```
public static List<String> nullSafeConversion(final String[] names) {
     // Initialize all to a list
     List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList(names);
     // Create a null safe Stream
     Stream<String> nameStream = namesList.stream().flatMap(Stream::ofNullable);

     // return collected list from stream
     return nameStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Generic type method:

```
public static <E> List<E> nullSafeConversion(final E[] e) {
    // Initialize all to a list
    List<E> eList = Arrays.asList(e);
    // Create a null safe Stream
    Stream<E> eStream = eList.stream().flatMap(Stream::ofNullable);
    // return collected list from stream
    return eStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

How to call:

```
String[] names = {"Subarata", "Talukder", null, "Software Engineer"};
Integer[] marks = {100, 55, null, 25, 66, null, 88};
    
// Print all null safe items
for (String name : nullSafeConversion(names)) {
    // Show null safe data
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Subarata
Taluker
Software Engineer
```