# java convert double array to ArrayList<Double>

Tags: java

I've read and tried all methods mentioned int his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t). They all don't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
    public void test() {

    double[] closePrice;
    closePrice = new double[100];
    closePrice[0]=1.35456;
    closePrice[1]=1.35472;
    closePrice[2]=1.35472;
    closePrice[3]=1.35492;
    closePrice[4]=1.35489;
    closePrice[5]=1.35512;
    closePrice[6]=1.35489;
    closePrice[7]=1.35519;
    closePrice[8]=1.35493;
    closePrice[9]=1.35499;
    closePrice[10]=1.35511;
    closePrice[11]=1.35491;
    closePrice[12]=1.35489;
    closePrice[13]=1.35487;
    closePrice[14]=1.35484;
    closePrice[15]=1.35481;
    closePrice[16]=1.35462;
    closePrice[17]=1.35411;
    closePrice[18]=1.35421;
    closePrice[19]=1.35421;
    closePrice[20]=1.35392;
    closePrice[21]=1.35409;
    closePrice[22]=1.35432;
    closePrice[23]=1.35427;
    closePrice[24]=1.35436;
    closePrice[25]=1.35409;
    closePrice[26]=1.35394;
    closePrice[27]=1.35422;
    closePrice[28]=1.35379;
    closePrice[29]=1.3535;
    closePrice[30]=1.35341;
    closePrice[31]=1.35391;
    closePrice[32]=1.35394;
    closePrice[33]=1.35453;
    closePrice[34]=1.35445;
    closePrice[35]=1.35431;
    closePrice[36]=1.35459;
    closePrice[37]=1.35464;
    closePrice[38]=1.35465;
    closePrice[39]=1.35462;
    closePrice[40]=1.35456;
    closePrice[41]=1.35476;
    closePrice[42]=1.35475;
    closePrice[43]=1.35486;
    closePrice[44]=1.35474;
    closePrice[45]=1.35504;
    closePrice[46]=1.35562;
    closePrice[47]=1.35553;
    closePrice[48]=1.35548;
    closePrice[49]=1.35528;
    closePrice[50]=1.35555;
    closePrice[51]=1.35568;
    closePrice[52]=1.35542;
    closePrice[53]=1.35478;
    closePrice[54]=1.35451;
    closePrice[55]=1.35477;
    closePrice[56]=1.35478;
    closePrice[57]=1.35443;
    closePrice[58]=1.35462;
    closePrice[59]=1.3544;
    closePrice[60]=1.35473;
    closePrice[61]=1.35429;
    closePrice[62]=1.35401;
    closePrice[63]=1.35386;
    closePrice[64]=1.35396;
    closePrice[65]=1.35216;
    closePrice[66]=1.35242;
    closePrice[67]=1.35312;
    closePrice[68]=1.35292;
    closePrice[69]=1.3528;
    closePrice[70]=1.35355;
    closePrice[71]=1.35402;
    closePrice[72]=1.35419;
    closePrice[73]=1.35443;
    closePrice[74]=1.3537;
    closePrice[75]=1.35366;
    closePrice[76]=1.35321;
    closePrice[77]=1.35353;
    closePrice[78]=1.35332;
    closePrice[79]=1.35309;
    closePrice[80]=1.35307;
    closePrice[81]=1.35293;
    closePrice[82]=1.3534;
    closePrice[83]=1.35431;
    closePrice[84]=1.35608;
    closePrice[85]=1.35567;
    closePrice[86]=1.35572;
    closePrice[87]=1.35509;
    closePrice[88]=1.3548;
    closePrice[89]=1.35476;
    closePrice[90]=1.35444;
    closePrice[91]=1.35426;
    closePrice[92]=1.35406;
    closePrice[93]=1.35431;
    closePrice[94]=1.354;
    closePrice[95]=1.35377;
    closePrice[96]=1.3535;
    closePrice[97]=1.35284;
    closePrice[98]=1.35278;
    closePrice[99]=1.35302;

    ArrayList<Double> close =  new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(closePrice));
    // error in this line. 

}
```

The error I got is:

> Error:(159, 9) java: no suitable constructor found for
>   ArrayList(java.util.List)
>       constructor java.util.ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.util.List cannot be converted to int)
>       constructor java.util.ArrayList.ArrayList(java.util.Collection) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.util.List cannot be converted to java.util.Collection)

I've no idea why this simple task takes so much trouble. Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `Arrays.asList` returns a `List<double[]>`. You want a `List<Double>`, which you can only have if your array is of component type `Double`.

Comment: Type arguments can not be primitive.So you need to use the wrapper for double - `Double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your array as type `Double` and then you'll be able to use it, almost the same way you did:

```
Double[] closePrice;
closePrice = new Double[100];
...
ArrayList<Double> close =  new ArrayList<Double>();
close.addAll(Arrays.asList(closePrice));
```

Comment: Your other options include using Guava, or the Apache libraries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and another option (considering this example) is not using an Array at all (add all the elements to  the list directly).  But looking at the dup, the answer I liked best is the one that uses Java 8: `ArrayList<Element> arrayList = Stream.of(myArray).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`