# How to copy elements from `2d array` to `Arraylist`?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

folks, what is the technique of copying elements from `array` to `Arraylist`?

```
public DenseBoard(T[][] x, T fillElem){
      ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
      for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++){
              myBoard.get(i).add(j); //<<------ getting error!
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to initialize each member of myBoard in the outer loop:

### Untested Code Ahead

```
public DenseBoard(T[][] x, T fillElem){
      ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
      for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
          myBoard.add(new ArrayList<T>); //Gotta add something to stick stuff in
          for(int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++){
              myBoard.get(i).add(j); //<<------ no more error?
          }
      }
  }
```

Since myBoard is an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Ts, we need to give it somewhere to put the T's. Initially, myBoard looks like this:

```
[] <-- empty ArrayList
```

So we give it somewhere to put data for each row, like this

```
myBoard.add(new ArrayList<T>);
```

Now it looks like

```
[ [] ] <--- ArrayList with an empty ArrayList in it, ready to accept T's
```

We add some T's, and end up with this

```
[ [T1, T2, T3] ].
```

And on the next iteration, we'll end up with something like this

```
[ [T1, T2, T3], [T4, T5, T6] ]
```

Hope that cleared things up.

Comment: could you please explain this line? WHat does  `myBoard.add(new ArrayList<T>);` do?, @CollinDriscoll

Comment: It adds a new ArrayList<T> to myBoard. myBoard is an ArrayList of ArrayLists of T's. Initially it's empty. So we need to give it somewhere to put T's.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because your are trying to `get()` a value from `ArrayList` but not had inserted any value first. To do it your way, here is the correct code :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    ArrayList<T> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++){
        values.add(x[i][j]);
    }
    myBoard.add(values);
}
```

Just use the following function :

```
Arrays.asList(T...a)
```

In your case it will be done as :

```
ArrayList<T> myBoard = new ArrayList<>();
for(T[] arr : x){
    myBoard.add(Arrays.asList(arr));
}
```

1. Try to use `diamond operator <>` to make code more readable
2. Don't reinvent the wheel, use utilities provided at least by core libraries
3. Make use of `for-each` statement where you could

Comment: but I have 2d array in this case which is `T[][] x`. Would it cause any problems ? @afzalex

Comment: Obviously not. Just use `T` in the place of `Integer`, well I edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array).

```
new ArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(array))
```

creates a new `ArrayList` of `Item` elements from an input array. For two-dimensionals. In this case, you tried this:

```
public DenseBoard(T[][] x, T fillElem){
      ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
      for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++){
              myBoard.get(i).add(j); //<<------ getting error!
          }
      }
  }
```

The problem is that the line throwing the error assumes you have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`, but the inner element you try to refer to is not initialized. This should be a fix:

```
public DenseBoard(T[][] x, T fillElem){
      ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
      for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
          myBoard.add(new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(x[i])));
      }
      //Do something with myBoard
}
```