# Initializing objects into an arrayList from test class

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

Hey I'm new to Java and have been having difficulties with arrays. I'm trying to use either arrays or arrayLists to store a list of values from my test class. But I'm having on how to add set1 and set2 into my arrayList.

I have a test class with

```
Data set1 = new Data(new double[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    System.out.println("Set1: " + set1);

Data set2 = new Data(new double[]{-5, -4, -3, 1});
        System.out.println("Set2: " + set2);
```

Then my data class

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Data {

    public Data(double[] sets) {
        ArrayList<Double> sets = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

}
```

Comment: you can´t add `set1` and `set2` as they are of the type `Data` and your `ArrayList` requires a `Double` due to generics. You most likely want a constructor `Data(double[])` where you pass the `double` array. in there you could add the values to the `List`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create ArrayList from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your `Data` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Data {

    public Data(double[] sets) {
        ArrayList<Double> sets = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }

}
```

The `sets` variable disappears after the constructor returns, so there is no use declaring it there. You should move the declaration to the class level and assign a correct value to it in the constructor:

```
ArrayList<Double> sets;
public Data(double[] sets) {
    this.sets = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (double d : sets) {
        this.sets.add(d);
    }
}
```

Since you want to print the `Data`, you need to override the `toString` method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return sets.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you:

```
public Data(double[] array) {
    sets = new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(array));
}

public String toString() {
    return sets.toString();
}
```

Comment: How would I resolve set1 to a variable in my toString. Atm if I try to output I get the adress of set1 and set2.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create data class as:

```
class Data
{
   ArrayList<Double> obj;

   Data(Double var[])
   {
      obj=new  ArrayList<Double>();

      for(int i=0;i<var.length;i++)
      {
           obj.add(var[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Now create objects of this data class as:

```
Double val1[]={1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
Data set1=new Data(val1);

Double val2[]={1.0,25.0,36.0,44.0};
Data set2=new Data(val2);
```

Now add these objects of data class into arraylist as:

```
ArrayList<Data> sets=new ArrayList<Data>();
sets.add(set1);
sets.add(set2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using Java 8 streams,

```
class Data {

    List<Double> d;

    public Data(Stream sets) {
         this.d = (List<Double>) sets.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

Data setss = new Data(Stream.of("1.1","2","3.4","4","5"));
System.out.println("d list = "+setss.d);
```