# Streamreader to 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, streamreader

How do I  take the contents of a file using a Streamreader and place it in a 2d array.
The file is as follows:

```
    type1,apple,olive,pear
    type2,orange,nuts,melon
    type3,honey,grapes,coconut
```

So far my code is as follows:

```
     public static void invent()
    {
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader("food.txt");
        while (reader2.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            string[,] line = new string[1000, 1000];

             line = reader2.ReadLine();
        }


    }
```

Comment: do you speciffically need a 2d array or you can work with a better scenario?. A List for example.

Comment: scenario. so i need something where it can store the content  of the file in elements , separated by the ",". So in future i can select X1,Y1  (orange).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create ArrayList from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array)

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach for what you are trying to do is to have your splitted string into a `List<string[]>`. It would be much more easier to work with the data inside. I do not think two dimension array is the right approach. Look at this example:

```
List<string[]> splittedList = new List<string[]>();

string[] list = File.ReadAllLines("c:/yourPath.txt");

foreach (string s in list)
{
    splittedList.Add(s.Split(','));
}
```

Then you can iterate through the `List<string[]>` as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a static array like that, you should use a `List` that can grow as needed.

```
//Read the lines
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"food.txt");

//Create the list
List<string[]> grid = new List<string[]>();

//Populate the list
foreach (var line in lines) grid.Add(line.Split(','));

//You can still access it like your 2D array:
Console.WriteLine(grid[1][1]); //prints "orange"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  But how would I access the in the Y co ordinate if they were different amounts for example  type 1 may have four food items and type 3 may have 1 item. how would i do this using a loop? any help is appreciated