# accessing y coordinates from a list of string arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, grid-layout

So, I have a `list` which has an `array` of `strings` inside it, which (the arrays) are of different lengths.

```
foodmenu.menumethod();
var menugrid = foodmenu.menumethod();

// method for category lists

List<string> ingcategory = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < menugrid.Count; i++)
{  
     ingcategory.Add(menugrid[i][]);       
}

return ingcategory;
```

I want to be able to access all the elements in the `string` array (which are the arrays inside the list) using a loop but a number of elements the `string` array contains are not the same for each item in the list.

what the current `menugrid` variable contains:

```
1 a b c d e f 
2 a b 
3 a b c d e f g h i j
4 a b c d e f h
5 a b c d
6 a b 
7 a
```

currently, it only goes to one to seven and I have to manually place the second coordinate in the place of `Y` due to me getting out of bound errors.

Comment: why would you prefer a `for` loop over `foreach`? is there any reason behind it?

Comment: I dont know how to use a foreach loop if they are better alternatives i would be happy

Comment: _i have a list which as an array of strings inside_ show the type of that list /  signature of foodmenu.menumethod

Comment: What type is menugrid? Is it a 2d array?

Comment: 'list<string[]>' a list string array

Comment: the actual generation of the variable is a previous question i have asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378834/streamreader-to-2d-array i used the first answer

Answer (score 0):

use a `foreach` loop to access each `string[]` within the `menugrid`, that way you don't have to concern yourself with indexers.

```
foreach (string[] array in menugrid)
{
    // do something with the array           
}
```

or if you want to go another level deeper:

```
foreach (string[] array in menugrid)
{
    // do something with the array if necessary
    foreach (string item in array){
       // do something with the items within the array
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can traverse through your list of array of strings:

```
foreach(var menu in menugrid)
{
    foreach(var item in menu)
    {
        // TODO: Do something with each item
        Console.Write(item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```