# How to make object array of varying length?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am making an ArrayList of objects that will be displayed in a ListView. When I use `Object[] ObjectList = new Object[length]` it expects an exact length for the entire array upon creation. I have tried making the value of the length an int variable but it appears it doesn't update the length when the variable is changed. How can I accomplish this? I am kinda new to Java, so thanks to anyone who helps out!

Comment: `Object[length]` doesn't create an ArrayList, it creates an array. Use `new ArrayList<Object>` to create an ArrayList of Objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array?rq=1](Create ArrayList from array). Though I'm a bit unsure...

Answer (score 3):

Use `List` interface of Collections framework. E.g. `List<String> data = new ArrayList<>()`. You can conver it to array if you need with `data.toArray()` method

Comment: how can I specify the object type of the array when using the toArray() method?

Comment: The type of the array will be inferred from the type of list items. E.g. List<String> will produce a `String[]` array

Comment: I have an ArrayList of a custom object (Obj)  using List<Obj> list = new ArrayList<>; and when I have the Array, created by Obj[] tempList = list.toArray; It claimed that it needs Obj[] but found Object[].

Answer (score 2):

**Arrays** have a fixed size. Once an array is created, the size can't be changed any more. You can only create a new array and change the reference your variable is holding!

In other words - assume you start with:

```
Object[] items = new Object[5];
```

Later you figure: I need more space:

```
Object[] moreItems = new Object[15];
```

And then you can use [System.arraycopy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java) to copy the content of the first array into the second.

For the record:

- List/ArrayList are *not* Arrays.
- `ArrayList` uses the approch described above under the covers to implement that "dynamically" growing array experience for you

Answer (score 2):

I will not repeat what others have very well said.

About your actual problem, `android.widget.ListView` is designed to be populated with array type.
Now if data used to populate the `ListView` have a size variable and may often changed, you have an alternative : using an `ArrayList` wrapped in an  `ArrayAdapter`.

During the `onCreate()` method you could create the adapter and set it to the `ListView` :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, 
                 android.R.layout.listview,
                 arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Now, you don't have any longer the problem of the fixed size array as you use an `ArrayList` that doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: Yep, ArrayList and ArrayAdapter is the answer. Take a look at https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView