# Java Print the integers at the even indexes of the passed in array

Tags: java

```
public class Exercise2
{
    public static void printEvenIndex(ArrayList list)
    {
        //Print the integers at the even indexes of the passed in array

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //instantiate an ArrayList named values nand fill with Integers
        //fromt the supplied list
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[] nums = {1, 5, 7, 9, -2, 3, 2};

        System.out.println("Expected Result:\t 1, 7, -2, 2,");
        System.out.print("Your Result:\t\t ");
        printEvenIndex(values);
    }
}
```

Im a little confused on what to do when it tell me to Print the integers at the even indexes of the passed in array.

Comment: Always solve "big" problems by breaking it into smaller ones. First initialize `values` with integers. Then, can you print all of them ? If so post the code of how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Array indices start at 0, so in this array- `int[] nums = {1, 5, 7, 9, -2, 3, 2};`, the number `1` is at index 0, `5` is at index 1, `7` is at index 2, and so on. You're asked to print the numbers at the even indices, so - `1, 7, -2, 2`.

You access array elements by the array name, and the position, like `num[0]` gives you 1.

Here's a good starting point to read up more on [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

---

Looking at your methods, I'm assuming you'll want to [use `asList()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array) to pass an `ArrayList` to the `printEvenIndex()` method. The difference in case of an `ArrayList` is that you'll be using [`get(index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) method to fetch an element from the arraylist.

Even in that case, you'll need to check that you pass in an even index as the value to `.get()`.

Comment: "instantiate an ***ArrayList*** named values and fill with Integers"

Comment: "Java Print the integers at the even indexes of the passed in array"

Comment: The requirement is to print values from array list

Comment: If the OP understands how to solve the actual problem - "print elements at certain indices", i'm sure he can adapt the solution to work with any DS - array, or arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like a for loop to iterate through your num[] array starting from 0 and adding 2 to the counter each iteration so it only prints the even indexes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i+=2)
        {
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
        }
```

The output of this code would be : 1 7 -2 2

Comment: The only problem is that i have to put it in the top method... so im not sure

Answer (score 0):

I think this is work for you.

```
public static void printEvenIndex(ArrayList list)
{
    //Print the integers at the even indexes of the passed in array
    System.out.print("Expected Result:\t");

    for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {
       if((i%2==0)||(i==0)) 
          System.out.print(list[i]+"\t");
    }
}
```