# Remove Item from List not working in Java

Tags: java, android, list

i have a List which contains a few Strings from the strings.xml.

A random number determines which text from the List will be shown.
Then this text should be removed from the list.

Unfortunalely, the List.remove(index) ist not working for me.

What am I doing wrong?

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">ReadQuestions</string>
    <string-array name="questions">
        <item>Text 1</item>
        <item>Text 2</item>
        <item>Text 3</item>
        <item>Text 4</item>
        <item>Text 5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    List<String> questions;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


questions = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions));
setNewText();
}

public void setNewText(){
        int rnd = new Random().nextInt(questions.size());
        textViewBehind.setText(questions.get(rnd));

        questions.remove(rnd);   // Not working
        Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Doesn't pop up somehow

    }
```

Has anybody an ideo why the remove method isn't working and why everything after that method isn't processed. It feels like there is some return statement in the remove method. 
Im new to Java, but even if the onCreate method is just called once, could it be possible the 
questions = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions));
is called every cycle and fills the List again?

Best regards

Comment: `Arrays.asList` creates an *immutable* list, meaning you can't change it. I would suggest you use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: What do you mean *its not working*? What is happening? Is there an error/exception?

Comment: How can I use an ArrayList with getResources.getStringArray, Nicolas?

Comment: Jason, nothing happens, no crash, no error message.

Comment: @andyyy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/create-arraylist-from-array

Comment: do like ArrayList<String> questions=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions)));